# Set Logged in UserDetails in one layer and access it in DAO layer in any java MVC

Tags: session, model-view-controller, controller, dao

I want to set loggedin user some where from controller layer and access it in DAO layer for updating modified_by column. How i can do it without passing user data as method parameter down the layer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't. Session can't be used from one context to another but what you can do is can pass session method/context to method/context till n-tiers.

for example DAO.cs

```
public int receiveUserDetails(Session userDetails)
{ 
  // Use userDetails here
}
```

and here is uor BAL.cs

```
receiveUserDetails(Session);
```